# Magento 2 : Update product position in category using mysql (magento 2)

Tags: magento2

I am working on module to Update product position in category using mysql (magento 2).
As i will directly using 1000+ sku at a time.

I have to implement using mysql.

is their any way it can be done in class or any reference available how its done in core ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Why are you not using import functionality of magento? you can achieve the same thing using that also

Comment: That also does not work with more then 6000 skus

Comment: Import them in batches than its better and secured than writing mysql queries,  which are time consiming and more chance of disturbing the whole setup of catalog .

Comment: That's right, but client wants to update in a single execution.

Comment: That's why there is no other way then using mysql implementation.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: more chance of disturbing the whole setup of catalog what does this mean @Asssd